# How do I recover from a corrupted context

Tags: node, storage

It seems my context or data dir is corrupted. How can I restore my node?

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of Pierre: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1370#note_575210288

To recover "quickly", you need to start over from a fresh snapshot. (you could even probably generate a snapshot from your datadir as long as you take as `--block` something older than the problematic block but the simplest may be to download one from somewhere)

To track the root of the issue and understand why/how your context got corrupted, please provide the following to help Tezos developers with debugging:

- the log of the first time your node failed to validate the block (and a bit of history above)
- if possible, the `store` and `context` folders of your datadir ( these probably occupy several GBs, so it might be complex to move them around).